# Flutter FireStore - initialize instance after clearing persistence

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling `await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();` in-order to clear the cached data after a user signed out.

Per the documentation, you only call it after terminating the firestore session.

But after trying to retrieve the data again after login, I am getting an error:

"The client has already been terminated"

***EDIT: THIS HAPPENS ONLY ON FLUTTER WEB. On flutter mobile (Tested on Android) it is working fine.***

***So how can I initialize the instance after terminating it?***

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
```